# Error translating native regular expression to RegExp object with variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this script that takes a regex pattern as a variable and then test it to see if it matches

If I run

```
var r = /[^(^$|\s+)]+/
r.exec(" ")
>> null
r.exec("a ")
>> ["a "]
```

But when I run

```
var r = new RegExp("[^(^$|\s+)]+")
r.exec(" ")
>> [" "]
r.exec("a ")
>> ["a "]
```

I can't translate the native syntax to the object RegExp without changing the expected behaviour. One of my attempts were outputing opposite results, when the first regex were null, the second regex was the matched array, and vice versa

@edit
as far as I can see, if I use `match` instead of `exec` the same happens

@edit

Expected result is: match anything that is not an empty string
https://regex101.com/r/qD0bO3/1

Any ideas?

Comment: Your original regex looks fishy. What are you trying to do?

Comment: question updated. if the regex is not correct, why does it even match depending on the method?

Comment: `match anything that is not an empty string` why not use `/^\S+$/`

Answer (score 1):

You need negative look-ahead `(?!...)` instead of negated character class `[^...]` (which is a character class and thus only match a single character):

```
/^(?!\s*$).*/m
```

`^` anchors the search to the beginning of a line, and we check that the line is not empty, or consists of only whitespaces with the negative look-ahead `(?!\s*$)`. When the look-ahead succeeds (the pattern is not found), `.*` is used to consume all characters to the end of the line. Look-ahead does not advance the position of the match, so we need `.*` at the end to consume the actual text.

The `m` flag at the end makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of the line, instead of the default behavior which matches the beginning and the end of the whole string.

Alternatively, here is the pure regular expression approach:

```
/^\s*\S.*/m
```

We will make sure that the line has at least one non-whitespace character, and match the rest of the line.

Comment: hello there, one character string gives me null: `var r = new RegExp("^(?!\s*$).*")
r.exec("s")`

Comment: @VictorFerreira: Use RegExp literal: `var r = /^(?!\s*$).*/m`. For constructor (not recommended in this case): `var r = new RegExp("^(?!\\s*$).*", "m");` (need to double up ``\`` for the string literal syntax.